# Why should i change Laravel namespace?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm not a PRO with Laravel. I've already learned the basics, but there's one thing that I don't understand... Why should I change the default `App` `namespace` with the command:

```
php artisan app:name NewName
```

Everywhere I see they say to change it, but I don't get why. If I want to keep it as just `App` I will have some problems in the future of development?

Comment: No need. If you like `App\FooBar` that's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It just does not affect anything to your app development. But with an app namespace, it just looks much more organized, cooler and friendlier to you.

Compare `Facebook\Foobar` with `App\Foobar`, which one is cooler and easier for you to recognize? Primarily, personal-based opinion :)